# Объединить синонимичные метки [next.js] и [nextjs]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Объединить:

- [nextjs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nextjs) - 78 вопроса;
- [next.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/next.js) - 56 вопросов.

Эти метки нужно объединить, так как ими уже отмечены примерно соразмерные параллельные множества вопросов.

Comment: в какую сторону синоним?

Comment: @Grundy Логично было бы в сторону [tag:nextjs], по аналогии с [tag:reactjs].

Comment: а, блин, есть смысл в направлении?